How to run a ksh script in Cygwin through Windows Batch file
I'm currently using Cygwin to run a kornshell script that parses files present in the /home/myname/files directory. I've been doing this manually so far.
Is there a way to run this automatically. Essentially, I would like Cygwing to do the following.

Cygwin opens up and navigates to the desired directory.
The execute the ksh script.

So far, I have the following batch script, which opens up Cygwin,
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
setlocal enableextensions
set TERM= cd /d "%~dp0files" && .\bash --login -i

The issue is twofold. The above only gets me into the /home/myname directory. It doesn't proceed to the /files directory. Also, how would I go about passing a command to run the present .ksh script in the /files directory?

I use the following windows command script to run bash scripts in cygwin:
@ECHO off
set UNIXDISK=C:\cygwin64
SET MAKE_MODE=UNIX
set UNIX_PATH_ADD=%UNIXDISK%\bin;%UNIXDISK%\usr\local\bin;%UNIXDISK%\usr\X11R6\bin
set backup_path=%PATH%
rem include change to directory of script
cd %~p1
echo bash -c %~nx1 >junk1.cmd
set path=%UNIX_PATH_ADD%;%PATH%;.
call junk1.cmd
set PATH=%backup_path%
erase junk1.cmd

Save in something like "bash_run.cmd" in a directory in your path. It changes to the directory of the script and runs it in bash. I think it should work with ksh. The script should be specified with a full path.
call bash_run.cmd <your script (full path)>

